# How to know primary and secondary microcontroller in an embedded system are ready to transfer data over a communication bus

Tags: microcontroller

My embedded system has two microcontrollers: primary and secondary. Both boots up at time. There is heavy data transfer between these two controllers. Before data transfer between controllers they should be up and running. How primary will know secondary is up and running or vice versa? Please provide the approach.

I have implemented the GPIO Toggle approach. But need any better approach.

My GPIO handshaking approach:
Primary and Secondary controller shares two GPIO. For both controllers one GPIO will be input and other will be output. Lets say, GPIO 'A' is output for Primary and input for secondary and GPIO 'B' is output for Secondary and input for Primary. Ideally GPIO status is HIGH. Both controller signal each other using GPIO about their readiness. Once Primary controller boots and is ready to take part in data transfer, it pulls down GPIO 'A' and polls for GPIO 'B' before any data transfer. Once Secondary controller boots, it will pull down another GPIO 'B' to notify primary that it is ready. Secondary also sense GPIO 'A' to check whether Primary is up and running before taking part in data transfer.
Same happens when Secondary boots before Primary.

Drawback of this approach is: Two GPIO has to be dedicated for handshaking. I am short of GPIOs.

Please provide any better alternative. Thanks

Comment: Well you have implemented something and don't provide us your approach. That doesn't it make easier to give suggestions.

Comment: elaborate on the approach you have and what is bad about that would imply something else is better?

Comment: If you have a shared memory, you can reserve a flag in memory to signal if the other controller has already reached the ready state. However, you need to have some kind of mutual exclusion on that memory address.

Comment: Some ideas: 1. Use the IRQ line if available, plus one GPIO.  2. You can use a TX/RX pair (reverse on other side) and at predetermined baud rate send some special control sequence to indicate readiness (e.g., data packets and special 'ping' packet) -- two IO total - full duplex.  3. Use the Dallas one-wire protocol (see iButton) -- one IO total - half-duplex.

Answer (score 0):

If I want to know if my communication is valid (connector plugged in, participants up and running...) I include some way to check the data in my protocol.

If the communication is bidirectional, the sending controller expects an predefined answer from the receiving controller. If the answer is missing / wrong, I know there has to be a problem.

I2C for example includes the ACK bits. If they are not coming, I know my communication partner is not listening.

SPI has two lines: out and in. If you send, check permanently which data is coming in. If it is invalid, abort.